# Fastest way to take elementwise sum of two Lists

Tags: scala, list, performance, apache-spark, elementwise-operations

I can do elementwise operation like sum using **Zipped** function. Let I have two Lists **L1** and **L2** as shown below

```
val L1 = List(1,2,3,4)
val L2 = List(5,6,7,8)
```

I can take element wise sum in following way

```
(L1,L2).zipped.map(_+_)
```

and result is

```
List(6, 8, 10, 12)
```

as expected.

I am using **Zipped** function in my actual code but it takes too much time. In reality My List Size is more than **1000** and I have more than **1000** Lists and my algorithm is iterative where iterations could be up to **one billion**.

In code I have to do following stuff

```
list =( (L1,L2).zipped.map(_+_).map (_  * math.random) , L3).zipped.map(_+_)
```

size of **L1**,**L2** and **L3** is same. Moreover I have to execute my actual code on a cluster.

What is the fastest way to take elementwise sum of Lists in Scala?

Comment: If you are looking for runtime efficiency then consider using arrays instead of lists.

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk I try to change List with Array but I do not think that will increase speed.

Comment: To squeeze more efficiency use pre-allocated arrays to store temporary results and do operations on them using while loops and access by index.

Comment: Moreover, instead of inventing the wheel I would recommend using some efficient linear algebra library like: https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze

Comment: And, in case if you will not be satisfied by performance then try SIMD-based solutions like: https://astojanov.github.io/blog/2017/12/20/scala-simd.html

Comment: Also since you said that you would have many big lists and you need to execute this on a cluster, you may consider implement this on a cluster framework like **Spark**. Or simple consider other language instead of **Scala**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am using Spark. and inside MapPartitionWithIndex i am converting Iterator to List and performing operation on that List

Comment: @user12140540 It would be good if you open a new question involving **Spark** also I would not convert the **Iterator** to a **List** you already do an expensive operation there for creating a low performance datastructure.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks and goof recommendation of opening a new question .

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use a **Streaming** implementation, taking advantage of the *lazyness* may increase the performance.

An example using **LazyList** *(introduced in Scala `2.13`)*.

```
def usingLazyList(l1: LazyList[Double], l2: LazyList[Double], l3: LazyList[Double]): LazyList[Double] =
  ((l1 zip l2) zip l3).map {
    case ((a, b), c) =>
      ((a + b) * math.random()) + c
  }
```

And an example using **fs2.Stream** *(introduced by the [`fs2`](https://fs2.io/) library)*.

```
import fs2.Stream
import cats.effect.IO

def usingFs2Stream(s1: Stream[IO, Double], s2: Stream[IO, Double], s3: Stream[IO, Double]): Stream[IO, Double] =
  s1.zipWith(s2) {
    case (a, b) =>
      (a + b) * math.random()
  }.zipWith(s3) {
    case (acc, c) =>
      acc + c
  }
```

---

However, if those are still too slow, the best alternative would be to use plain arrays.

Here is an example using **ArraySeq** *(introduced in Scala `2.13` too)* which at least will preserve immutability. You may use raw arrays if you prefer but take care.
*(if you want, you may also use the [`collections-parallel module`](https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections) to be even more performant)*

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq
import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._

def usingArraySeq(a1: ArraySeq[Double], a2: ArraySeq[Double], a3: ArraySeq[Double]): ArraySeq[Double] = {
  val length = a1.length

  val arr = Array.ofDim[Double](length)

  (0 until length).par.foreach { i =>
    arr(i) = ((a1(i) + a2(i)) * math.random()) + a3(i)
  }

  ArraySeq.unsafeWrapArray(arr)
}
```

Comment: Zipped is faster than Zip.

Comment: @user12140540 in the **LazyList** example? I doubt it. The advantage of `zipped` over `zip` is that the former is lazy whereas the last is strict. But, since a **LazyList** is already lazy both should behave the same. I supposed that the problem with your code was that each `map` call was actually strict, thus you iterated every list a couple of times, that is why I proposed the use of full _lazy_ collections that will guarantee only one traversal at the end. Or if that wasn't enough for the performance you need, there is nothing that can surpass plain **Array** operations.